# How can I structure Laravel route function to created dynamic routes?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Assume I have a model, table named item, items

```
+----+-------------+
| id |    name     |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Burger      |
|  2 | Large Pizza |
+----+-------------+
```

I want my routes function (which generates routes) to generate route automatically.

Sample Route function

```
Route::get('item/{item}', itemController@getitem)->name('item');
```

This is what it is returning

```
route('items',['item' => 1]) => mysite.com/item/1
route('items',['item' => 2]) => mysite.com/item/2
```

This is what I need it to return

```
route('items',['item' => 1]) => mysite.com/item/burger
route('items',['item' => 2]) => mysite.com/item/large-pizza
```

I want a to add a functional working like this

```
function getItemLink($item){
    $item = Item::find($item);
    return env('APP_URL').'/item/'.strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$item.name);
}
```

PS:- I don't want to change the calling function `route('items',['item' => 1])` but I can change code in routes files. Reason being, the function is spread all over the location.

Comment: What's the contents of `getItem()`?

Comment: I don't have function named ``getItem()`` anywhere but I do have ``getItem($id)`` 
 in controller which returns the Item in Json Model.

Answer (score 1):

You should

- create a migration that will add a `slug` column in the table
- fill the `slug` field of every row with `Str::slug($item->name)`
- tell Laravel you want to retrieve your model via the `slug` field

```
// YourModel.php
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

- Change your link generting lines with `route('items',['item' => $item])`

I know you hate this last point but it's necessary. Laravel is already aware on how to build links using routes and [Bindings](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding)

With this last point, also, if you want to switch back to links with id, you just need to remove the `getRouteKeyName()` method from your model.

Comment: But sometimes in view I don't have $item but $item_id only.

Comment: Just send to the view the `$item` object and you're set, it's better to let Laravel handle the bindings so you don't have to change your routes in the future

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty common, and what `slugs` are for. Since you can't use `Large Pizza` in  a URL, you need to "sluggify" it to `large-pizza`, then ensure that slug is unique in your database.

With those conditions met, you can change your route to

```
route('items',['item' => "large-pizza"])
```

Note: The way you have it defined `Route::get('item/{item}' ...)` will actually work for slugs just fine.

Next, change your code to query for an item matching that `slug` instead of an item matching an `id`. For example:

```
public funciton getItem($itemSlug){
  $item = Item::where("slug", "=", $itemSlug)->first(); // firstOrFail(), etc.
  return view("items.detail")->with(["item" => $item]);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change ``route('items',['item' => "large-pizza"])`` I want to use ``route('items',['item' => 2])`` because its all over the place already. Also at some point of time, if i want to change ``-`` with ``+`` I have to change ``route('items',['item' => "large+pizza"])`` all over the place again which I don't want.

Comment: Also at some point of time if wanted to change ``mysite.com/item/large-pizza`` to ``mysite.com/item/Large-Pizza`` I have to change it all over the place again, which I don't want.

Comment: I guess I'm confused then. What exactly are you trying to do? Basically, you can't have both `mysite.com/item/1` and `mysite.com/item/burger`; your `getItem()` function won't know how to handle it.

Comment: I could do it in the slug way, but I only have access to $item_id in views, how will I use ``route('items', ['item' => $item.slug])`` if I don't have $item but $item_id?

Comment: Add some logic to pass `$item_slug` to the view? That being said, if you've accepted the other answer, you may want to look into opening a new question. Passing data to a view is not complicated, and there are plenty of resources on Stackoverflow on how to do that, so start there, and open a new question if you need to.

Comment: Yep, I know that Passing ``$item_slug`` is not complied but I have to Use this routes in many pages, I have to do changes in each of the 20+ controllers. My client's code is already fu**ed up.

Comment: Welcome to the world of refactoring... If you can pass the `$item`, then you can make a method on the `Item` model that returns that URL as a string. But you'll still have to adjust all the instances of it being hardcoded.